# ionic 4 same page after refresh without going to login page

Tags: ionic4, refresh

Hi I'm new to cordova and ionic 4. I'm developing app with ionic 4  and angular. Every time I do small change in the code "Ionic serve" just logout of the application. I Just want to remain in the same page like web because it's very annoying the app always logout in small changes.How can I do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Kavi, you will need to provide more details and actual code used to make your context known. Otherwise, this is too vague to answer as its unclear how login flow is setup and refresh just reloads the web-app

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I used native storage to store token after login. I run the mobile app in browser and in each changes the app refresh and logout. My main question I don't want the app to reload  after every change in the code. Below is the small snap of code used to login "this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 's/api/mobile/user/login', data, options ).pipe(

Comment: try read this tutorial to keep the login state, https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-angular-guards-tutorial/#.XwVue5MzbOY .in the previous ionic version we can stop live reload by using `ionic serve -b --no-livereload` but it seems that command already deprecated. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/turn-off-autoreload/15326